# Next and previous post link in same terms custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I've created a `custom taxonomy => cat-blog` in my `custom post => blog`, `cat-blog` have 4 `terms` and each `terms` have list of post belong to that `term`

**Example of terms:**

*- City Updates (`4 post belong`)

- Home Tips (`6 post belong`)

- Real Estate Guide (`8 post belong`)

- Real Estate Industry (`9 post belong`)*

and using this **query**

```
<?php
     $query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'post_type' => 'blog', 'blog-cat' => get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'blog-cat' )));
     while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
     ?>

   <?php 
// content here
?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
 <?php

 ?>
```

to display 2 post in same category, 
AND I just want to put `next` and `prev` pagination, so I can navigate the rest of the post, belong to that `term`.

Comment: Is this on a page template?

Comment: yes... WP_Query above use to display post by category I put that code in `taxonomy.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever change the main query for a custom query on archive pages and on the home page. The main query already does what you want to do. Trying to run a custom query to try and get the same result is like reinventing the wheel. It also causes problems with pagination

**SOLUTION**

- First, remove your custom query, and return to the main loop. The following is all you need in your taxonomy.php

  ```
  if( have_posts() ) {
     while( have_posts() ) {
       the_post();

       //REST OF YOUR LOOP

     }
  }
  ```
- Use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) in conjuction with the [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) if you need to alter the main query. For instance, if you need 2 posts per page on your taxonomy page, do the following in functions.php

  ```
  function so26499451_custom_ppp( $query ) {
      if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_tax() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
          $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '2' );
      }
  }
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'so26499451_custom_ppp' );
  ```

You can now paginate as normal without any problems. You will now see two posts from the specific term that you clicked on per page on your taxonomy.php.